# Combine two observables then transform the result

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, flatmap

I have a REST endpoint that I am calling with Angular Http.
I need to chain two calls, then use the results from each to create an object to return.

Pseudo code:

- POST new entity to server and get a UID back
- PATCH entity content to server, using UID returned
- create an object that combines entity content and UID
- return object to caller (subscribe)

I thought this would do it, but I get an error;

```
addClient(clientData) {
   let clientUid;
   return this.http.post(`/clients`, clientData)
     .flatMap((newClient:any) => {
       clientUid = newClient.name;
       return this.http.patch(`/spec/${clientUid}`, clientData)
       .flatMap((updatedClient:any)=> {
         return {
           uid: clientUid,
           ...updatedClient,
        }
      })
   });
}
//consume
 this.clientService.addClient(clientData)
    .subscribe((response:any) =>{ }
```

> TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

How can I:

- fix the error and have addClient return my desired object?
- Also, is there a way I can consume the UID in the final flatMap without having to set the local variable (clientUid )?

Comment: `flatMap` is expected you to return an Observable. but you're returning an object. Instead, you should use `.map` for that bit

Comment: Doh! I actually started with map there, but changed to fix another issue. Changing it back does indeed work. Thanks.

Comment: @user184994 if you add an answer I'll mark it as accepted. If you have any ideas on point 2, that would be most helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.flatMap` function is expecting you to return an `Observable`, but you're actually returning an object.

If you want to transform the value, instead you should be using `.map`

Regarding using `clientUuid`, seeing as your `map` is being called from within the original `flatMap`, you should just be able to use `newClient.name`

Answer (score 1):

There are some error + improvement can be done in your code.

1. Improvement: you don't need to nested your `flatmap` call.
2. Error: you don't need the second `flatmap`. What you need is `map`

I have created a demo for your problem - https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-rxjs.